# Syncing two databases from different vendors directly? (Oracle & MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I'd like to know if there's a way to send data from an Oracle database directly to a MySQL database, without having any middle app in between (let's say a PHP which accesses tchem both).

Is there any way to achieve this? Would be great if MySQL could also send details back once in a while, no need to have any calculations just simple plain old data migration.

Comment: You must have some middleware connecting the two databases and transferring the data from one database to another.

Comment: If you need a tool to do that easily try [Talend open studio for data integration](https://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio/). It's quite a simple tool to learn, especially if you have some coding experience with Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the embedded JVM installed in Oracle database (a.k.a. OJVM), you can load the type 4 MySQL JDBC driver in a database schema then do "JDBC callout to MySQL" from within an Oracle session.

Reach out to me if you want more details (kuassi dot mensah at oracle dot com).

Answer (score 0):

There many ways of connecting Oracle with any other database.

you can use ojdbc or jdbc drivers to connect to marian db or the old mysql.

see the links below.

https://blog.pythian.com/how-to-access-mysql-from-oracle-with-odbc-and-sql/

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, using the Oracle Heterogeneous Services.
You can setup a database link from the oracle db to the mysql database and have a scheduled job spool and dump data into the mysql database at intervals or at specific calls.

Oracle supports heterogeneous services to allow data in non-Oracle(MS Access, SQL Server, MySQL etc.) database to be queried using SQL. This support has been in the form of transparent gateways, which are vendor specific, or generic connectivity which uses ODBC or OLEDB to make the connections.